# JSX expressions must have one parent element. How to remove this in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite

Started learning Vue3, used Vite CLI to create the project and got this highlighting.

Is there anyway to turn it off?

[image]

Comment: It's specific to the place where you have this highlighting which is an editor, not anything else

Comment: @EstusFlask Sorry for not adding this in detail, yes it's in VSCode highlighting. I assume this is something related to react, but why is this showing in the Vue file? Is there a way to disable it?

Comment: Means that Vue syntax is not correctly handled. It's the responsibility of a plugin, namely Volar. It's unknown if you use it already

Comment: @EstusFlask I have installed it and also when I tried directly through npm init vue@latest instead of npm create vite@latest, that highlighting is gone.

Comment: You maybe are using Vetur rather than Volar. You can't have several node in the root of your template (as in React) while using Vue2. So check and disable if you have Vetur installed, and if it's the case disable it.